# Count digit of numbers from the range [a, b] which contains at least one of three digits that are 2, 5, 8

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to count digit of numbers from the range [a, b] which contains at least one of three digits that are 2, 5, 8. I try to use normal way by using nested loop with C but it takes 6s to complete. I want to solve this problem by taking less time (1s)
My codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int countDigit(long n) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 
    while (n != 0) {
        int num = n%10;
        if  (num == 2 || num == 5 || num == 8) {
            count++; 
        } 
        n = n / 10; 
    } 
    return count; 
}

int main() {
    long count = 0;
    for (int i = 11; i<= 100000; i++) {
        count += countDigit(i); 
    }

    printf("Count: %ld", count);

    return 0;
}
```

E.g: 2135 -> count = 2, 821 -> count = 2
Input: 1 <= a <= b <= 100,000,000 
Output: The number of digits 2, 5, 8. 
Sample input: a = 11, b = 100000
Sample output: 149997
Time limit: 1s

Please, give me some ideas to solve this problem. I don't need the codes.

Comment: You may get more interest by posting your code attempt.

Comment: do some maths first. If you only consider the last digit then every 10th number has a `2` as last digit. Same for `5` and `8`. Considering more digits is just a bit more complicated.

Comment: btw we cannot help you improving code when you do not show the code. I dont even see how you would use nested loops to solve it. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: ... and please decide for one language

Comment: do you want to count the numbers that have one of the digits or do you want to count how often `2`,`5` and `8` appear as digit?

Comment: @RamblinRose Thank you for your recommendation, I've added my codes to the post.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818  I want to count how often 2,5 and 8 appear as a digit in the numbers in [a, b]

Comment: Note that count of 2,5,8 in interval [a, b] is count of 2,5,8 in [0, b] minus count of 2,5,8 in [0, a-1].

Comment: @ÖöTiib What do you mean? How do you count 2, 5, 8 digit in a number without using loop?

Comment: For a value upto 100000 you don't need to send it as long, int is sufficient.

Comment: There is no need for a loop.

Comment: Hint: What's the result for the range [0,999999999]? You should be able to solve it on paper, or even in your head. Now the issue becomes finding the answer when the range goes to an arbitrary number.

Comment: @ManojBanik " int is sufficient. "  --> C specifies `int` having a _minimal_ range of +/-32K. Portable code would use `long`, as OP did, to accommodate 100,000,000.  IAC, this is only a minor linear performance concern.

Comment: Counting digits of each integer number in the range [a,b] is not efficient. For the first stage of an efficient solution, ask yourself this question: "What is the count of integer numbers in the range [a,b] ending with the decimal digit `d` ?"

Comment: Sounds like a task for dynamic programming to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
    100,000,000 in < 1 millisecond, or even
100,000,000,000 in < 1 millisecond also?
```

There are a couple things that can be noticed.

**1. Powers of tens**

For 10, result is 3, for 100 => 60, 1000 => 900, ... Jumping from one power to the next, we are counting the 3 digits 2/5/8 10 times more, adding the counting of the lower powers... Meaning 10 to 100, we multiply the initial 3 x20, from 100 to 1000, x300...

The general result, for 10^n numbers, is

```
R1 = 3 * n * 10^(n-1)
```

For x * 10^n, where x > 1, we simply multiply R1 by x since we have it x times. Then

- if x > 2 we must add 10^(n-1) (since the right side of the number will be repeated with that 2 in front),
- if x > 5 we add it again (to add it twice)
- if x > 8, again (3 times added)

The final case is when x is either exactly 2 or 5 or 8, in this case it will be "used" only once (since we have x * 10^n), and thus we add 1 to the result.

**2. Number breakdown**

We notice also that a number `dcba` can be written with a sum of

```
a.10^0 + b.10^1 + c.10^2 + d.10^3
```

and this is not news. However, what is more interesting, is that

```
count(dcba) = count(a.10^0) + count(b.10^1) + count(c.10^2) + count(d.10^3)
```

meaning by breaking down our number, we can use our first calculation rule for as many digits the number has. Again, if `d` or `c` or `b` are exactly 2 or 5 or 8, we must add the right part of the number (since we must "exhaust" that right part). For instance for `1234`, we'll have

```
count(1000) + count(200) + [34] + count(30) + count(4)
```

The complexity of the algorithm based on the number of digits is  (log is base 10)

```
O(log(n))
```

**3. Program**

In the C program below, the function in charge of counting for the powers of 10s would be called 5 times for `54321`. Should be less that 1 millisecond! (I used `/usr/bin/time`)

(using longs to allow bigger numbers)

```
long count1(int d, int tens) {
     long power = 1;
     for(int p=0 ; p<tens ; p++) power *= 10; // 10^tens
     long powerless = power / 10;             // 10^(tens-1)
     long one = 3 * tens * powerless;
     long r = d * one;
     if (d > 2) r += power;  // Add the 2s
     if (d > 5) r += power;  // the 5s
     if (d > 8) r += power;  // the 8s
     if (d == 2 || d == 5 || d == 8) r ++; // Add 1 if exactly 2/5/8
     return r;
}

long count(long n) {
     long res = 0;
     int tens = 0;       // log10(n)
     long power = 1;     // 10^tens
     long remainder = 0; // Right part of number
     while (n) {         // Breakdown n
          int d = n % 10;
          if (d) {
                res += count1(d, tens);
                if (d == 2 || d == 5 || d == 8) {
                     res += remainder;
                }
          }
          remainder += d * power;
          tens ++;
          power *= 10;
          n /= 10;
     }
     return res;
}
```

Usage: from `a` to `b`

```
long result = count( b );
if (a > 1) result -= count ( a-1 ); // subtract result for `a-1`
```

Examples: 11 to ...

```
        100,000,000 => 239999997
    100,000,000,000 => 329999999997
100,000,000,000,000 => 419999999999997  (took 1 millisecond)
```

Answer (score 1):

To determine the count of digits 2,5 and 8 in the range [a,b], you need only to determine the count of those digits in the range [0,l]. You then determine the count of digits in the range [a,b] by subtracting the count of digits in the range [0,a-1] from the count of digits in the range [0,b].

The count of digits in the range [0,l] can be determined more easily by decomposing l in a sum of power 10 values. For instance, the count of digits in the range [0,234] is the count of digits in the range [0,200] + the count of digits in the range [1,30] + the count of digits in the range [1,4]. Luckily, the count of digits in the range [1,L] is the same as in [0,L] since the value 0 has a count value of 0.

The problem is thus reduced into determining the count of digits in the power 10 value Dx10^N with D in the range 0 to 9 and N in the range 0 to 8. Let C(D,N) be the count of digits in the range [0, Dx10^N].

We can easily deduce by hand C(D,0) : (0:0, 1:0, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1, 5:2, 6:2, 7:2, 8:3, 9:3). By using the initial program we can also determine the values C(D,1) for the different D : (0:0, 1:3, 2:7, 3:19, 4:22, 5:26, 6:38, 7:41, 8:45, 9:57). We can see a pattern in these numbers: (0:0=0x3+0, 1:3=1x3+0, 2:7=2x3+1, 3:19=3x3+10, 4:22=4x3+10, 5:26=5x3+10+1, 6:38=6x3+2x10, 7:41=7x3+2x10, 8:45=8x3+2x10+1, 9:57=9x3+3x10). The value with D=1 is thus a relevant value. In this case it is 3, but with bigger N, this value G(N)=3xNx10^(N-1). For instance for 10000, N=4 and G(4)=12000=3x4x10^3. You can verify this value with the initial program for the range [0, 10000].

The counts of digits for a power 10 upper limit L=Dx10^N is then C(D,N)=DxG(N)+K(D,N). When N=1, we have G(1)=3. Using the pattern we found before, we deduce the following K(D,1) values (0:0, 1:0, 2:1, 3:10, 4:10, 5:11, 6:20, 7:20, 8:21, 9:30). For instance, for 60, C(6,1)=6x3+20=38.

From this, and by probing again with the initial program, we deduce the general function K(D,N). For instance, when N=3, we have G(3)=3x3x10^2=900. Using the program we get for 3000 C(3,3)=3700=3x900+1000. The function K(D,N) is thus defined as follow for the different value of D (0:0, 1:0, 2:1, 3:10^N, 4:10^N, 5:1+10^N, 6:2x10^N, 7:2x10^N, 8:1+2x10^N, 9:3x10^N). We can verify with the count of digits in the range [0, 8000] which yields 9201. C(8,3)=8xG(3)+K(8,3)=8x900+2001=9201.

We now have all the pieces of the puzzle to compute the count of digits. We must first create a function that computes the number of digits 2, 5 and 8 in the range [0,L] where L is a power 10 value to get the value C(D,N). For this we need to compute G(N) and K(D,N).

We then decompose a given boundary L in a sum of power 10 values and compute the sum of count of digits in each range.

Here is the program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

// power10 returns 10^n. Requires n >= 0 && n < 9. 
int power10(int n) {
    static int tbl[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000};
    return tbl[n];
}

// count_digits_in_power10 return the number of digits 2,5 and 8 in the range [0, d*10^n].
// Requires d is in the range [0,9] and n is in the range [1,8].
int count_digits_in_power10(int d, int n) {
    int g = 3*n*power10(n-1);
    switch(d) {
    case 0:
        return 0;
    case 1:
        return g;
    case 2:
        return 2*g + 1;
    case 3:
        return 3*g + power10(n);
    case 4:
        return 4*g + power10(n);
    case 5:
        return 5*g + power10(n) + 1;
    case 6:
        return 6*g + 2*power10(n);
    case 7:
        return 7*g + 2*power10(n);
    case 8:
        return 8*g + 2*power10(n) + 1;
    case 9:
        return 9*g + 3*power10(n);
    }
}

// count_digits_to_limit returns the number of digits 2,5 and 8 in the range [0,l].
// Requires l is in the range [0, 100000000].
int count_digits_to_limit(int l) {
    assert(l >= 0 && l <= 100000000);
    int c = 0;
    for(int n = 8; n > 0; n--) {
        int p = power10(n);
        int d = l/p;
        assert(d >= 0 && d <= 9);
        if (d > 0) {
            c += count_digits_in_power10(d, n);
            l -= d*p;
        }
    }
    assert(l >= 0 && l <= 9);
    if (l < 2)
        return c;
    if (l < 5)
        return c+1;
    if (l < 8)
        return c+2;
    return c+3;
}


int main() {
    int a, b;
    printf("bound a: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a < 0 || a > 100000000) {
        printf("a is invalid: %d\n", a);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("bound b: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (b < 0 || b > 100000000) {
        printf("b is invalid: %d\n", b);
        return 1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        printf("a (%d) is bigger than b (%d)\n", a, b);
        return 1;
    }
    int c = count_digits_to_limit(b);
    if (a > 0)
        c -= count_digits_to_limit(a-1);
    printf("count of digits 2,5 and 8 in range [%d, %d] is %d\n", a, b, c);

    return 0;   
}
```

Here is the output:

```
bound a: 11
bound b: 100000
count of digits 2,5 and 8 in range [11, 100000] is 149997
```